# Combobox's first element gets populated with selected value of the last one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm having an issue where the option I select in a combobox will get "sent" somehow to the next one. I'm loading strings from an SQL server database using the `DataSource` class.

I have a small form to select country -> state -> county-> city. With each box getting populated depending on the previously selected one.

So for example if I select state Florida, on the next box the first element will be Florida, even though its not on the counties table. Same for counties(Broward shows up on cities).

Here is the code for the `SelectionChangeCommited` method of the combobox.

```
        private void cboDirProvincia_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            cboDirCiudad.DataSource = null;
            cboDirDistrito.DataSource = null;

            try { 
            cboDirCiudad.DataSource = dirs.ListarCiudadesPorIdRegion((int)cboDirProvincia.SelectedValue);
            cboDirCiudad.DisplayMember = "nom_ciudad";
            cboDirCiudad.ValueMember = "id_ciudad";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what the line… `dirs.ListarCiudadesPorIdRegion((int)cboDirProvincia.SelectedValue);` is returning. How is the data: `country -> state -> county-> city` organized? There are many ways to do this and I am guessing “how” you do this will depend on “how” the data is organized. IMHO a somewhat simple approach would go something like this…

Comment: There is a `DataSet` with four (4) `DataTables` such that each table would correspond to the “country, state, county and city” info. Theoretically, the “country” table would have two fields “CountryID” and “Name.” The “state” table would have three fields: “StateID”, “CountryID” and “Name.” The “county” table would have three or four fields: “CountyID”, “StateID”, an optional “CountryID” and “Name.” The same idea would apply to the “city” table.

Comment: With this `DataSet` you could then set each combo box to the same `DataSet` as a `DataSource` such that the “DataMember” of “each” combo box would correspond to the proper “country”, “state”, “county” or “city” `DataTable` in the `DataSet`. Then, when the user selects a “country”, you simply “filter” the “state” table based on the selected “country.” Then use that as a data source to the “state” combo box. The same idea would apply for the counties and cities combo boxes.

Comment: The main point would be to set something up such that you DO NOT keep re-querying a data base every time the user changes a combo box selection. Filtering is going to be much quicker in addition to avoiding unnecessarily clobbering the data base with needless/redundant quires. Again, this is just one possible way to do this. It would help to clarify how the original data is organized.

Comment: Hello JohnG, to answer to your comments: 1. ```dirs.ListarCiudadesPorIdRegion``` returns a ```DataTable``` and it expects an integer parameter to look for all the states that match the country id. 2. The data is laid out exactly as you say but its all on the database. 3. Basically thats what I do it but I'm always querying the database for the list of all states/counties/cities that match the parents id. 4. Would there be some way to query the database base for multiple tables and use it locally?

Comment: To your comment… _”Would there be some way to query the database base for multiple tables and use it locally?”_ … I can not answer that. If the data you use is coming from a data base, then I would be surprised if you couldn’t. However, this is most likely going to depend on how the data is organized in the data base and what “unique/key” fields define the tables. Can you show what tables AND what fields in those tables are returned after calling the above method for a single “country”?

Comment: My previous comments “assume” certain “key” fields exist in certain tables. If there is NOT a “StateID” field in the “counties” table, then you would have to add this if you wanted a table with ALL counties from ALL states. It would be the “StateID” field you would use to “filter” the “counties” table. I am guessing that the data you get back from the database may NOT have this field which means it wont work as described since you won’t know which county goes with which state. This is all speculation, and a clearer picture of what is return from the data base will dictate the best approach.

Comment: Lastly, it sounds to me as a minimum, you may have to re-query the data base each time the user changes the “COUNTRY” combo box. After that you should be able to apply the filtering as described. However as already stated, if certain “key” fields are missing in the table, then filtering may be a challenge.